# A starter implementation for Genetic Algorithm

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I have lately been interested in Genetic Algorithms, and sought to write a simple Genetic Algorithm code as a beginner to understand it. I took a function `f(x)=x^2` and wanted to minimize it over the domain `{0,1,....31}`. Now i know that the optimum value is `31`, but i wanted to implement it using GA so I wrote a code. I wish to know (i) is my code even close to what GA does, (ii) If it is a decent beginners level code, what all improvements can be done in this, (iii) Since in this problem i know that the value should be `31`, but when does my GA stop?, (iv) doesn't the algorithm really depend on the random number generation, so  I can by chance get the solution in the first iterate only, and hence can be misleading at times, so what all parameters should be checked. Here is my crude code (pardon me for that, this is my first try at it)

```
%Maximize the function f(x)=x^2;
% Using GA in the domain [0,31];

% We take 4 initial candidates as solutions only 5 bits
x=rand(1,20);
A=(x<0.5);


% Checking for randomness
A=reshape(A,4,[]) ;

B_DEC=bi2de(A,'left-msb');
Y=B_DEC.^2;
%FIT=B_dec./sum(B_dec(:))% Fitness function
for loop=1:3


    [~,index]=sort(Y,'descend');
    B_DEC=B_DEC(index)   ; % Sorting the values
    FIT=B_DEC./sum(B_DEC(:));


    MATING_POOL(1:2)=B_DEC(1,:);
    MATING_POOL(3:4)=B_DEC(2:3,:);
    MATING_POOL=de2bi(MATING_POOL,'left-msb');

    CHOOSE=randi([3,4]);
    C=(rand(1,5)<0.5);
    ind=find(C>0);

    New(1,ind)=MATING_POOL(1,ind);
    ind=find(C<=0);
    New(1,ind)=MATING_POOL(CHOOSE,ind);


    C=(rand(1,5)<0.5)
    ind=find(C>0);

    New(2,ind)=MATING_POOL(CHOOSE,ind);
    ind=find(C<=0);
    New(2,ind)=MATING_POOL(1,ind);


    if mod(CHOOSE,4)==3
        C=(rand(1,5)<0.5);
        ind=find(C>0);

        New(3,ind)=MATING_POOL(2,ind);
        ind=find(C<=0);
        New(3,ind)=MATING_POOL(4,ind);


        C=(rand(1,5)<0.5);
        ind=find(C>0);

        New(4,ind)=MATING_POOL(4,ind);
        ind=find(C<=0);
        New(4,ind)=MATING_POOL(2,ind);

    else
        C=(rand(1,5)<0.5);
        ind=find(C>0);

        New(3,ind)=MATING_POOL(2,ind);
        ind=find(C<=0);
        New(3,ind)=MATING_POOL(3,ind);


        C=(rand(1,5)<0.5)
        ind=find(C>0);

        New(4,ind)=MATING_POOL(3,ind);
        ind=find(C<=0);
        New(4,ind)=MATING_POOL(2,ind);
    end

    B_dec=bi2de(New,'left-msb');

    Y=B_DEC.^2;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, I haven't fully understood your code, though given from your description of the problem and a glance of the provided code do I think you need to revisit some basic concepts of GAs.

- Your population is not genetically encoded. You have not defined a genetic translation of your genotype (the genetic representation) to the phenotype (the function the genetically encoded genotype translates into). An example would be the following: Let's reuse your genetic search space being described as integers in the range [0; 31]. Your genetic encoding is the **translation of the genotype** (in this case an integer) **into a function**, e.g.: f(a) = ax^2 - a.
- While your fitness function returns a value that can be interpreted as fitness is it not a legitimate fitness function in the sense that the input to your fitness function is not a function. As an example is a proper fitness function when reusing above's genetic encoding the calculation of the Mean Squared Error between f(a) and x^3 + x^2 for x between [0;10]
- Another fundamental concept of GAs is a defined way of mutating a genotype or crossing over 2 genotypes. An example of mutating a GA is the addition of a random value between -5 and 5. An example of crossover between 2 genotypes is the average value of both.
- Genetic algorithms are usually a population based optimization method, so you have to define multiple genotypes, compare their fitness, selectively breed (mutate and crossover) the fit ones and remove the low performing ones in each genreation.
- And to answer 2 of your specific questions: A GA is as boundless as its genotype search space. Since the genotype search space is limited in your example does the GA stop when the search space is exhausted. GAs are also often to a large extent based on randomness. Therefore can the best solution be found in the first generation.

Shameless plug if you would like to read up on some fundamental concepts about Neuroevolution (which is basically Genetic Algorithms with the constraint that all genotypes translate into Artificial Neural Networks): 
https://towardsdatascience.com/9068f532f7f7